# Converting instruction involving CPU registers to memory instruction

Tags: assembly, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am new to LLVM and understanding the instruction generation by LLVM. As part of this, I am trying to convert a basic boolean instruction to use memory registers directly as operands. For example, in the below IR, I would like the `and` operation to use `%a` and `%b` instead of `%11` and `%12`.

```
%11 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4 \n
%12 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4 \n
%13 = and i32 %11, %12\  
store i32 %13, i32* %d, align 4\n
```

Do I need to write a new `and` instruction for this, or is there another easier way?

Comment: `%a` and `%b` are pointers, ANDing them together means something else than ANDing together the values loaded from them. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: I would like to fetch the values pointed by %a and %b as part of the instruction itself. I am looking for an instruction something like this. %13 = and i32* %a, i32* %b. This is to understand if I can remove the two load instructions before and by directly obtaining the content of the pointer %a and %b

Comment: Ok that cannot be done then, loads and stores through pointers can only be done explicitly

Comment: I think the backend should match such patterns if an appropriate instruction exists for the CPU you are compiling for. The backend is not just taking one LLVM instruction and generating code for it but it matches patterns of LLVM instructions. Therefore these operations do not have to be combined at the LLVM level and as @harold pointed out, they cannot be. This optimization is more about providing the right instruction definitions for the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's feasible. Memory in LLVM cannot be accessed without explicit loads or stores.